# Laravel 5.5 make a search of multiple entities

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a Laravel 5.5 project. The idea of the project consist on make a search page for finding information about the second world war. I have data of soldiers, historic documents and fights.

The idea of the search page is to enter one word or a set of words (like in Google) and filter the soldiers, documents and fights names in one query.

I have been investigating but all what I have found is about making search from one entity, and I need a search for three entities.

I have seen the official documentation of Laravel https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scout, but seems that works for one entity.

My database is relational MySQL. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: what do you mean by "entity"?

Comment: i suggest you use https://www.algolia.com/ for `full-text search `

Comment: entity => model

Comment: Have you looked into elasticsearch? You could store them in ES and reindex data when an entity changes...not that straight-forward I know...

Answer (score 1):

There is no preferred way to search in all models however if you want to make search on multiple models then you would have to create a `search` table which will store all the record's title or other columns that you'd like to search on and make it as polymorphic relation which will then be used to other models for linking and then you can fetch results through the relation.
Eg:

Post model:

```
public function search(){
     $this->morphMany(Search::class,'searchable');
}
```

Search model:

```
public function searchable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

Then you'd make a search to the search model and fetch results like

```
$search->search('search text here')->map(function($data){
   return $data->searchable; // Fetch post
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with my package if you ready to add Elasticsearch to your project
https://github.com/matchish/laravel-scout-elasticsearch#search-amongst-multiple-models